# Как устроен модуль random в python под капотом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Какой исходный код, по которому создаются псевдослучайные числа, от чего зависит их случайность в `python 3.x`?

Вроде как есть способ их создания с помощью температура процессора.

Находил [данный](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py) код, но по нему не пройтись дебагером, чтобы понять логику генерации чисел

**P.S.**

Учитывая, что питон написан на `C`, то мб и реализацию нужно смотреть на `C`?

Comment: Случайности - не случайны (c) Угвэй

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно алгоритмы генерации (псевдо) случайных чисел основаны на получении каждого следующего числа на основе предыдущего (предыдущих) с помощью какой-то хитрой функции. При этом начальное значение зависит от какого-то "зерна" (seed), которое как раз инициализируется каким-то "гарантированно" случайным числом, типа температуры или текущего времени, а дальнейшие числа генерируются фактически детерменированно (не случайно) - если установить одно и то же начальное зерно, то после его установки будет генерироваться одна и та же последовательность значений.

Конкретно по поводу реализации в Python, нужно смотреть сишный модуль [_randommodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c), и в начальных комментариях указано, что код основан на [http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/%7Em-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html) , где в заголовке указано, что это вариант алгоритма Вихрь Мерсенна (Mersenne Twister). Общее описание этого алгоритма можно почитать например на Википедии: [Вихрь Мерсенна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: Благодарю, то что и искал, интересно в этом теперь покопаться

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду на Github, существует класс `Random`, который используется для создания экземпляров, чтобы получить независимые генераторы. Также имеется возможность использовать его подклассы, если необходимо использовать собственный генератор (в этом случае можно переопределить методы `random(), seed(), getstate(), setstate()`). `seed()` используется для того чтобы указать свое "зерно" псевдорандомизации, которое является исходными данными для формулы. Зерном может быть к примеру системное время в миллисекундах в настоящий момент времени, которое будет соответственно всегда меняться. Вообще сам модуль random содержит множество функций, связанных с эмуляцией случайности (перемешивание элементов последовательности и т.д.)

Comment: Тогда каким образом происходит перемешивание, в какой момент кода происходит всевдовыбор числа? По-моему в этом репозитории гитхаба нет раскрытия это момента

Comment: А зачем так глубоко вникать в это? Для чего может пригодиться это знание на практике?

Comment: Мне интересно, как в сфере, где все построено на алгоритмах, может создаваться что-то что является потенциально случайным. То есть кто-то написал код, который не поддаваясь какой либо логике создает случайно (не от чего не зависящее?) число

Comment: @Cowboyserg, абсолютно случайных чисел не может быть в природе)) Все от чего то зависит) Даже человек, когда его просят назвать случайное число - никогда не сможет назвать число, которое у него не всплывет в памяти, как потенциальная ассоциация с чем либо